Problema con BillingNotEnabledMapError
Estoy desarrollando una web para uso personal y he insertado un mapa de Google Maps para realizar busquedas. Hasta ahora ha funcionado correctamente, pero ahora me sale este error

Esta página no puede cargar google maps correctamente
En localhost si que me funciona bien, es cuando lo subo a la web cuando me sale este fallo de For development purposes only, el problema es que si que tengo una cuenta de google cloud y asociada una tarjeta de credito valida.
Necesito ayuda para que me funcione de nuevo el mapa en linea
He intentado poner otra tarjeta pero no me soluciona nada y si que tengo activo las cuentas y he puesto el API key en mi app pero sigue sin funcionar

Asegúrate que el api key está habilitado para el dominio de la web donde lo subiste.
